# TinyMCE adds <pre> tag when inserting from Word

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have several Drupal 6 sites which use the WYSIWYG module along with TinyMCE. For one of my sites, whenever I use the Paste From Word icon, it adds a < pre > tag with the class "mceItemHidden".

In addition, if the text is long enough, it does this strange thing where I click the "Insert" button in the Paste from Word window, the text appears in the main TinyMCE box, there is a brief pause, and then each paragraph is on a single line, which creates the horizontal scrollbar that is as long as the paragraph.

Has anyone experienced this, and do you have any idea why this is happening? I've tried changing my theme and various WYSIWIG settings and this is still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting from word is an odd thing. I couldn't say for sure but MS seems to tweak it now and then to make it especially difficult to translate (while making sure that it still renders well in IE)

Do you get the same issue in the tinyMCE [offical demo](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php), if not you could try upgrading your FCK editor.

Comment: No, I don't get the same issue when I try the official demo. I also don't get it when I try on most of my Drupal sites, it's just one of my sites. That's why I feel like maybe there's a setting I have wrong or something, but I'm not sure which one. I've done a lot of trial and error, but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting from word to begin with is a pain in the.... It's still a fight for us even with FCKeditor.  It was a fight when we used Tiny as well.  All that nasty xml and  tags were brutal on our CSS.

You might check your drupal filters and the way that tiny sanitizes stuff.  I forget where all that is.  We used tiny for a while, then switched to FCKeditor.  We switched for the image upload support.  Much better than tiny.  Anywho...

Answer (score 0):

Something must have been corrupt. I just completely removed TinyMCE from the libraries directory, and uninstalled the WYSIWYG module. I reinstalled everything, and things seem to be working (for now).